# how to manage secrets for different environment in serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework

I am trying to figure out how to manage secrets for different environements while creating serverless applications

my serverless.yml file looks something like this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${opt:stage}
    SOME_API_KEY: // this is different depending upon dev or prod

functions:
  ....
```

when deploying i use the following command

```
serverless deploy --stage prod
```

I want the configuration information to be picked up from AWS parameter store as described here: 
https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-secrets-api-keys/

However I do not see a way to provide different keys for development or prod environment.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I put prefixes in my Parameter Store variables.

e.g.

```
common/SLACK_WEBHOOK
development/MYSQL_PASSWORD
production/MYSQL_PASSWORD
```

Then, in my `serverless.yml`, I can do...

```
...
environment:
    SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${ssm:common/SLACK_WEBHOOK}
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${ssm:${opt:stage}/MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

You should be able to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I created a serverless plugin for this, because I was facing the same issue and didn't find a plugin for it. You can see the plugin here: https://github.com/robin-thomas/serverless-aws-secrets

The idea is that you shall have environment variables (that are secrets and hence having dummy values) that are already loaded by Serverless Framework, will be replaced by the secret values from AWS Secrets Manager by the plugin.

So that means, you need to have different environment variables for different environments (can use different `.env.*` files). Then use different secret keys in AWS Secrets Manager for each environment.

This way I don't have to keep the secret in my GitHub repo, and still have secret support in my serverless deployments.

---

Run below command to install the plugin:

```
$ npm install --save-dev serverless-aws-secrets
```

Add the plugin to serverless.yml:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-aws-secrets
```

Now, if you have environment variables that looks like below:

```
MYSQL_USERNAME=secret:MYSQL_USERNAME
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret:MYSQL_PASSWORD
```

the plugin shall search for secrets `MYSQL_USERNAME` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD` (you can configure the plugin), and then replace it within the deployment package.